# Difference of my object between edit and object mode

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, object-mode

I'm learning to use Blender, for plan drawing by design projects. I'm very new in this program and not familiar with 3D design.
I was working in the *Edit mode* for quite a long time and then switched to the *Object mode*. My object was totally different, but the render from *Edit mode* was still OK. I made quite a lot of "intersect-knife" by working on my object and I think this destructured my drawing. But can somebody explain this (look screenshots)?
Now, a few minutes after this screenshot, the entire drawing in *Edit mode* is like this one in *Object mode*. Strange or not?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you've given a Displace modifier to your object, it changes its appearance, disable it

Answer (score 1):

It's the displacement modifier that is causing the issue. The output of the displacement modifier is not visible in edit mode, but when you switch back to object mode the mesh looks weird. Just delete the displacement modifier if you are not using it.

Some Screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not checked the button  show the modifier in edit mode.

if you check that  you will get the same result in edit mode and object mode.

[image: display modifier in edit mode]